# How do you plot trail_price and trail_offset?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my strategy I have an exit condition like this:

```
strategy.exit("Long", trail_price = close, trail_offset = 50)
```

I want to plot the trailing price. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the trail stop loss price, e.g.

```
float trailStopLoss =  strategy.position_avg_price
 + <trail_offset> * (strategy.position_size > 0 ? -1 : 1)

trailStopLoss       := if strategy.position_size > 0
 math.max(trailStopLoss - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
 + high, trailStopLoss[1])
else                   if strategy.position_size < 0
 math.min(trailStopLoss - strategy.opentrades.entry_price(0)
 + low,  trailStopLoss[1])
```